# Return statement inside for loop with range not working

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, return, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to work on a problem based on python as:

```
`Given an integer,print the following values for each integer  from 1 to n :

Decimal
Octal
Hexadecimal (capitalized)
Binary`
```

What I did something like:

```
def print_format(number):
    for i in range(number+1):
        decimal=str(i)
        binary=str(bin(i))
        octa=str(oct(i))
        hexagonal=str(hex(i))
    return (decimal+' '+octa[2:]+' '+hexagonal[2:].upper()+' '+binary[2:])
```

print_format(5)

`'5 5 5 101'`

code returns only last set of value. But, what I'm expecting as,

`0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 10
3 3 3 11
4 4 4 100
5 5 5 101`

Part of the code as with `print` statement works perfectly fine.

```
def print_format(number):
    for i in range(number+1):
        decimal=str(i)
        binary=str(bin(i))
        octa=str(oct(i))
        hexagonal=str(hex(i))
        print (decimal+' '+octa[2:]+' '+hexagonal[2:].upper()+' '+binary[2:])
```

Can anyone please explain what I did wrong while using `return` statement?

Comment: Hint: Indentation.

Comment: the return statement should be outside for loop? right? That 's what I've done. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 2):

In your current attempt, you are looping through your input without doing anything. Return only sees the local variables after the last iteration and returns them. What you want is a generator:

```
def print_format(number):
    for i in range(number+1):
        decimal=str(i)
        binary=str(bin(i))
        octa=str(oct(i))
        hexagonal=str(hex(i))
        yield (decimal+' '+octa[2:]+' '+hexagonal[2:].upper()+' '+binary[2:])

mygen = print_format(5)

for i in mygen:
    print(i)
```

This should print your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Just save all strings in a variable spliting with `\n` and return it.

```
def print_format(number):
    result = ''
    for i in range(number+1):
        decimal=str(i)
        binary=str(bin(i))
        octa=str(oct(i))
        hexagonal=str(hex(i))
        result += decimal+' '+octa[2:]+' '+hexagonal[2:].upper()+' '+binary[2:] + '\n'
    return result

print(print_format(5))
```